# Should I use period pronunciation when reading poetry aloud?

Tags: pronunciation, poetry

I find that when I read older poetry, the rhyme scheme is sometimes broken and I assume that the problem comes from changes in pronunciation over time. For example, Poe keeps up a pretty impressive rhyme scheme throughout the Raven but it breaks on the lines:

> "Prophet!" said I, "thing of evil!
>
> prophet still, if bird or devil!

unless "evil" and "devil" rhyme.   When reading that line aloud, should I try to adjust the pronunciation so that they rhyme?  Or is it more important to pronounce words in a way that modern listeners will readily understand?

Comment: Also, large pat on the head offered to anyone who can offer a good suggestion of how to pronounce "evil" and "devil" so they rhyme.

Comment: Boofus, the obvious way to make them rhyme is to pronounce both *ev*'s the same way as the *ev* in [Evelyn](http://www.forvo.com/word/evelyn/).

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I'm not sure that it actually works for our format, since there is no correct answer.

Comment: It is likely Poe, master that he was, created a deliberate near-rhyme there to emphasize a crisis point.

Comment: _Devil_ is occasionally pronounced /'divəl/; there's an eye-dialect spelling "deevil" for it. But I don't think I've **ever** heard _evil_ pronounced /'ɛvəl/ like the first two syllables of _evolution_. Of course this doesn't answer the question about "should"; but then nothing does. You're on your own with poetry.

Comment: Neither [Basil Rathbone](http://town.hall.org/radio/HarperAudio/011594_harp_01_ITH.au) nor [Christopher Walken](http://youtu.be/cLSmhpwLdEQ) bothers. _The Raven_ is a comparatively recent work (1845) by an American author, so slavishly rhyming _evil_ and _devil_ was likely never Poe's intent.

Comment: I recommend that instead of changing your pronunciation, you change the offensive word. Exercise some of that poetic licence: _"Prophet!" said I, "thing of evil! / prophet still, if bird or **weevil**!"_

Comment: I voted to close because I feel that "Should I?" will result in discussion rather than a specific answer. If this question were rephrased to something more like "When did evil and devil rhyme?" or "How can I find out how a word has changed in pronunciation over time?" then I would consider voting to reopen.

Comment: On the other hand, if you read *enchanted* with the vowel of *father*, as the British do, it would come a lot closer to rhyming with *haunted* and *undaunted*, and it would be likely be Poe's intended pronunciation.

Answer (score 7):

Poe's poetry isn't old enough to have these words pronounced the same (*The Raven* was published in 1845). It's a printer's rhyme; so, No, those words should be pronounced normally.

Whether poetry like Chaucer's should be pronounced in a Middle-English fashion, or *Beowulf* in Old English, is another question altogether.

Comment: Exactly: here is a dictionary that shows they didn't rhyme in [1833](http://books.google.com/books?id=lxNzUsZYr78C&printsec=frontcover&dq=webster+dictionary&source=bl&ots=t7D_lCNN5q&sig=hWT9FNVmqHUMgYcfTJFxflpgs8E&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vC0QULe_Fcr50gGms4HgAw&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAA#v=snippet&q=calamity%20wicked&f=false).